# Using MacPython with MacPorts

Tags: python, macports

I've installed MacPython 2.7 from python.org. How to set it as default in MacPorts?

PS: #port select offers variants: '

- none(active)
- python2.5-apple
- python2.6-apple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MacPorts is not aware of MacPython, and therefore your best bet would be to install python 2.7 from the ports. That way you'll be able to select python 2.7 as default.

Another advantage of using python from MacPorts is that if you install ports that require python, MacPorts won't have to install python 2.7 a second time.

Comment: I see almost no differences between MacPython and python from macports.